# Add an option to a Child theme of Twenty Eleven

Tags: options, theme-twenty-eleven

I developed a child theme of Twenty Eleven. I need additional theme options, so i added a theme-options.php file inside my child theme's folder.

However, it appears the option page is still the 2011 theme's option screen. I can't either replace or add another one.

Question: what is the correct procedure to add options to a child theme?

In case you wish to see the code, [here is my theme-options.php](http://pastebin.com/mJnhjxL6) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/overriding-twentyeleven-theme-optionsphp) suggests that this isn't necessarily an intended Child Theme usecase so theme-options.php isn't explicitly overrideable. It indicates that you should rather be adding extra options using [`add_settings_field`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) and the [`admin_init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) hook.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that pointed me to a great solution: using add_settings_field is exactly what i needed. There is a very handy working example if anyone is having the same need: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API